# Changing the class of an <i> inside a <span>

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the class of an `<i class="icon-ok">` inside a `<span></span>`

The entire thing is like this:

```
<span class="enable"> Some Text
    <i class="icon-ok">  //This is all there is in here. Just one <i> and nothing else
</span>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.enable').live('click', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  self./ how do I tell it to look for the i/.removeClass('icon-ok').addClass('icon-remove');
});
```

Do you know a way this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
self.find('i').removeClass('icon-ok').addClass('icon-remove');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) since `<i>` is the children of your `.enable`:

```
$('.enable').on('click', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    self.find('i').removeClass('icon-ok').addClass('icon-remove');
});
```

Btw, `live` is deprecated as of jQuery version `1.7`. You should use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find('.icon-ok').removeClass('icon-ok').addClass('icon-remove');
```

---

```
$(this).find('i').removeClass('icon-ok').addClass('icon-remove');
```

---

```
$(this).children('i').removeClass('icon-ok').addClass('icon-remove');
```

---

```
$(this).children('.icon-ok').removeClass('icon-ok').addClass('icon-remove');
```

[this keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `find()` to search inside the clicked element...

```
$('.enable').live('click', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    self.find("i").removeClass('icon-ok').addClass('icon-remove');
});
```

Also, depending on what version of jQuery you're using you may want to us `on()` instead of `live()`, as that's been deprecated and I believe removed in the latest versions.  (I'm assuming there may be delegation involved, hence the use of `live` in the first place - have a look here for more info... http://api.jquery.com/on/)